# Coldfusion Query of Queries and dateformat error

Tags: coldfusion-2016

Documents indicate that I should be able to use the DateFormat() function to format inside of a QoQ,
But I am getting an error - I have tried cast() in addition to normal... I would like to return a query with date parts broken out (month and year) or filter based on datepart to pull back only record that match a month and year

So my objective would look like this in a normal Query.

```
SELECT
name
,date AS fulldate
,month(date) AS month
,year(date) as year
```

OR

```
WHERE
month(date) = arguments.month
and year(date) = arguments.year
```

However when I try to effectively do this in QoQ - I get a weird error.

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT 
directory + '\' + name AS fullpath ,
size ,
DateLastModified ,
dateformat(DateLastModified) AS month 
FROM getAllFiles 
ORDER BY DateLastModified
```

Here is the error

```
Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "(. Incorrect Select Statement, Expecting a 'FROM', but encountered '(' instead, A select statement should have a 'FROM' construct.
```

I have also tried this (and got the same error)

```
SELECT 
directory + '\' + name AS fullpath ,
size ,
DateLastModified ,
cast( dateformat(DateLastModified,'mm-dd-yyyy') as date ) AS month 
FROM getAllFiles ORDER BY DateLastModified
```

Help greatly appreciated
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> Documents indicate that I should be able to use the DateFormat() function to format inside of a QoQ,

Unfortunately, no. If you're referring to [this note](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/query-of-queries-user-guide.html) in the documentation, it's just poorly worded. I suspect they meant to say, "use [that] function outside the QoQ. For example, when outputting results to the browser withing a query loop".

> If you want to convert the date to its original format, use the
> DateFormat_ function and apply the "mm/dd/yy" mask._

QoQ's are **extremely** limited and currently only support these functions:

- Conversion functions: `CAST()`
- String functions: `UPPER()` and `LOWER()`
- Aggregate functions: `AVG()`, `COUNT()`, `MAX()`, `MIN()`

Could you elaborate on why you're trying to format the string column `DateLastModified` so we can suggest an alternative?